# Странное поведение вертикального padding

Tags: padding, отступы, html, css

Здравствуйте.
Проблема следующая вертикальные отступы по макету одни, а на практике, задавая эти размеры в css коде, в браузере отступы получаются больше чем надо.
Сбрасывал отступы для всего чего только можно, нет никакого результата. 
Помогите пожалуйста разобраться, может где-то что-то недоглядел.

Скриншот https://yadi.sk/d/OSQPOqjkTDVem

**html код**

```
  <header class="header">
    <div class="container">
       <nav class="header-menu">
         <ul>
       <li><a href="#">Главная</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Информация</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Новости</a></li>
         </ul>
       </nav>
    </div>
  </header>
```

**css**

```
body {
font-size: 16px;
width: 100%;
}
.container {
margin: 0 auto;
width: 940px;
}
/* Header */
.header {
background: #000000;
width: 100%;
border-top: 1px solid #242424;
}
/* Header --> menu */
.header-menu li {
display: inline-block;
}
.header-menu a {
color: #fff;
display: inline-block;
padding-top: 30px;
padding-bottom: 31px;
padding-left: 22px;
padding-right: 22px;
margin-right: -0.2em;
text-decoration: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Возможно различается размер того от чего считается padding? т.е. элементов li. Покрути значение line-height. Ведь высота строки это не расстояние между самым верхним и самым нижним пикселем текста.

Comment: Получилось! Благодарю за помощь.
Указал `.header-menu li { line-height: 1em; }` и всё стало на свои места.